# Can I connect my device to a Cisco pix VPN?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, vpn

We are buying quite a few tablets running Ice Cream Sandwich. Will it be possible for us to connect these tablets to our Cisco pix VPN? I know that Cisco have launched an app but it is for ASA. I have looked and not found anything that could do this.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco offers a rooted AnyConnect vpn client, and it turns out they also have an [ICS AnyConnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.avf&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmNpc2NvLmFueWNvbm5lY3QudnBuLmFuZHJvaWQuYXZmIl0.) available in the Play Store as well. This should help!

Comment: Cisco also offers AnyConnect apps specific to device manufacturers, you could try those out too. You'll see them in the play store on the left side in the "More from this developer" section

Comment: AnyConnect for Android requires Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance (ASA) Boot image 8.0(4) or later - I am not sure if this would work with our Pix

Comment: i don't know then :/ there are some other mobile vpn clients out there, but most are poorly updated and only apply to a narrow range of situations (having tried most of them myself :P )